# Cisco WLC 5508 HA licensing

Tags: wlc, cisco-wlc

I have one Cisco WLC 5508 with 40 access points and I need to implement HA.

So, as I understand, I need to buy the 5508 HA version of the controller. What is the differences between standard and HA versions? Or is it just different license/image? Am I right that I don't need to buy AP licenses for HA version?

Also, as I understand, I can buy additional 10 licenses for APs for the main controller and standard version of the WLC without additional licenses. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you are looking for is explained here :
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/wireless/aironet-1130-ag-series/qa_c67-714540.html

There is no HW difference that I'm aware of, however if you buy an -HA version of the controller, it can only ever be an HA controller, you can't convert it to be a primary controller, whereas the reverse is possible.

You don't need to buy licenses for the HA controller, as it "adopts" the primary's licenses for up to 90 days, the assumption being that that is enough time for you to repair your primary.

I'm afraid I do not quite understand your final question.